# How to compile gomuks on Ubuntu?

Tags: go, gomuks

Trying to compile [gomuks](https://github.com/tulir/gomuks), following its [insallation instructions](https://github.com/tulir/gomuks/wiki/Installation), I get this error:

```
$ go install
gomuks.go:25:2: cannot find package "maunium.net/go/gomuks/config" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/config (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ettinger/go/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/config (from $GOPATH)
gomuks.go:26:2: cannot find package "maunium.net/go/gomuks/debug" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/debug (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ettinger/go/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/debug (from $GOPATH)
gomuks.go:27:2: cannot find package "maunium.net/go/gomuks/interface" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/interface (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ettinger/go/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/interface (from $GOPATH)
gomuks.go:28:2: cannot find package "maunium.net/go/gomuks/matrix" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/matrix (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ettinger/go/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/matrix (from $GOPATH)
main.go:30:2: cannot find package "maunium.net/go/gomuks/ui" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/ui (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ettinger/go/src/maunium.net/go/gomuks/ui (from $GOPATH)
```

What is the reason, how to solve it?

Comment: The instructions say to use Go 1.13 or newer, and you're using Go 1.10.

Answer (score 3):

This repo uses Go modules feature and installation instructions clearly state it requires Go 1.13 or higher:

> 0. Install Go 1.13 or higher

From error messages it seems you have Go 1.10 which doesn't support modules (and likely also other features this repo depends on).

This error is caused by fact that prior modules support was added to Go in version 1.11; `go` tool was always looking up modules in `$GOROOT` and `$GOPATH` locations - and in your case it can't find them there.

Install Go 1.13 or higher to make the installation guide work. You can find recent enough packages in [backport PPA](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu) or install latest from official tarball available [here](https://golang.org/dl/).

Comment: `../../go/pkg/mod/maunium.net/go/mautrix@v0.8.0/crypto/olm/account.go:4:11: fatal error: olm/olm.h: No such file or directory
 // #include <olm/olm.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

Comment: Installation guide says you also need libolm-dev 2.x or better 3.x installed. You probably don't have that judging from that error message. Installing appropriate dev package should resolve the problem.